# BizTalk - Orchestration - Wcf.Action Must be a message part property of message part

Tags: biztalk

I'll answer this myself, just adding here for documentation if anyone else encounters it.

We are using dynamic WCF-SQL port.  I had it working in one test orchestration, but when I copied code to the real orchestration, it gave the error:

> Wcf.Action Must be a message part property of message part ...

and similar for each of the lines below (in a Message Assignment shape in a BizTalk orchestration).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just to remove the

> .Messagepart

Example:

```
SQLRequestMessage(WCF.Action) = etc...
```

The built-in WCF related promoted fields are on the message, not the parts of the message.

My test orchestration didn't use multipart message types, but in the real orchestration that I'm modified, our standard is to use them.

Once I saw the issue, it was obvious, but was knocking my head to figure it out for a while.